# JQuery method won't work after assignment to this variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Take the following code:

```
function animateTo(parent) {
    this.parent = $('#' + parent);
    console.log(this.parent)
    this.animator = function () {
        this.parent.animate({
            scrollTop: 5
        }, 5);
    }
}
test = new animateTo('data');
test.animator;
```

The first `console.log` shows the full object in the console, but when I try to run `this.parent.animate` I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'animate' animator.js:60
(anonymous function
```

Can anyone explain why that is?  I've tried `this.parent.selector` and I get the correct result, but if I try to call the animate method I get that error.

Comment: you should create another variable and assign to it `this`, something like `var self=this` and then use it in `this.animator` function as `self`

Comment: `this.parent` inside the anonymous function has no value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do:

```
function animateTo(parent){
    this.parent = $('#' + parent);
    var that = this;
    this.animator = function(){
        that.parent.animate({scrollTop:5},5);
    }
}
```

or

```
function animateTo(parent){
    return {
        parent: $('#' + parent),
        animator: function(){
            this.parent.animate({scrollTop:5},5);
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't like either of those options, you can always use `bind`, though you'll have to use a shim unless you don't care about old browsers.

For example (in modern browsers):

```
function animateTo(parent){
    this.parent = $('#' + parent);
    this.animator = (function(){
        this.parent.animate({scrollTop:5},5);
    }).bind(this)
}
```

or using underscore or lodash:

```
function animateTo(parent){
    this.parent = $('#' + parent);
    this.animator = _.bind(function(){
        this.parent.animate({scrollTop:5},5);
    }, this)
}
```

By the way though, it is customary to capitalize constructor functions as they are considered types (like classes in class-based object oriented languages).

Comment: Use of `self` or `that` is a cheap hack for not understanding how to compose scopes in JavaScript correctly. Not saying it doesn't have it's corner cases, but it's certainly not required for something this simple. I'm undoing my -1 because you provide a better solution on the second part of your answer.

Comment: @naomik interesting opinion :) so you should prefer the second or third options above.

Comment: Giving you +1 for providing two much more well-advised answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn a little more about [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) in JavaScript. The short version is: each time you open a new `function`, you create a new scope. Your code paste shows two nested scopes, where `this` in the inner scope does not match `this` in the outer scope.

Anyway, the solution is simple because you don't even need to use `this` in your scenario

```
function animateTo(parent){
  var $parent = $('#' + parent);
  console.log($parent)

  this.animator = function(){
    $parent.animate({scrollTop: 5}, 5);
  };
}

var test = animateTo('data');
test.animator;
```

---

It almost seems like you're trying to do something like this though.

The following is **opinion** for how I would write this code

```
var Animator = function(selector) {
  this.parent = $(selector);
};

Animator.prototype.animate = function() {
  this.parent.animate({scrollTop: 5}, 5);
};
```

Usage would look like this

```
var test = new Animator("#data");
test.animate();
```

Comment: The objects you get from your `new animateTo(parent)` will not have the `parent` property from the OP.

Comment: @Andbdrew, I don't have `new animateTo(parent)` in my code. I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: In the line `var test = new animateTo('data');`, the `test` object will not have a `parent` property

Comment: @Andbdrew that was my bad; I was thinking ahead in my followup example that uses `new`. The first example is not intended to use `new`.

Comment: I gave the answer to @Andbdrew and due to the binding which solved my problem.  There was much more code involved, but I edited for brevity.  Also knew about scoping, but didn't catch it.

Comment: Andbdrew awarded you the answer due to the .bind(this) which was the solution.  I edited problem above for brevity.  There was in fact a high order function involved also and I had no choice but to bind.  I tried to upvote @naomik's answer, but it won't let me due to lack of reputation so soooooo sorry naomik. :(  Thank you both so much for the help!